# Filling up NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've got the code below to fill up an array of notifications. This array is needed to fill up a menu in my iOS app with notifications.

```
// extract specific value...
NSArray *switchValues = [res objectForKey:@"data"];

NSLog(@"%@", switchValues);

for (NSDictionary *switchValue in switchValues) {

    NSString *text = [switchValue objectForKey:@"text"];

    NSLog(@"%@", text);

    [self.notificationsArray addObject:text];

}
```

Further down the line I then do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSMutableArray *titles = self.notificationsArray;
    cell.textLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

However, I keep getting an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you initialized the notificationsArray and also made sure the switchValues count is greater than 0?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do

```
[notificationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

instead of

`NSMutableArray *titles = self.notificationsArray;
    cell.textLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row];`
?

If you really dont want, at least do
`NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.notificationsArray];`

And in the first piece of code, what are the Console Logs? Are you sure you enter in the for loop?